# Append data to Google Spreadsheet using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, phonegap

I'm building a web app using Google Spreadsheet as a Database. In a few words, my app read information from the GSS after a user request and show some results. If the user can't find what he needs, he can send a message filling a form.

Now, the datas in this form should be registered in a second Google Spreadsheet. I was able to do this - with a big help from users of this platform - using Google Apps Script but this method do not allow me to come back to my pages and keeps running everything generating a frame in the script page.

I read all of Google Sheets API but I can find a way to do what I need using JavaScript: I cannot use Java because I will convert my website with **PhoneGap** and it only allows HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

Is there a way to do the same that the code below does **using JavaScript and Google Sheets API?** Could you please make an example I could use as a guide?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

S.

That's the code I used in gs: it works but I need something like this **client side** using JavaScript.

```
    function doPost(e){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("myID").getSheetByName('SheetName');
var column = 1; 
var colArray = sheet.getRange(2, column, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
var maxi = Math.max.apply(Math, colArray);


var id = maxi+1;
var name = e.parameter['name'];
var surname = e.parameter['surname'];
var serial = e.parameter['serial'];
var eMail = e.parameter['mail'];
var text = e.parameter['text'];
var area = e.parameter['area'];
var date = new Date();
var ans = ""
var flag = "Work In Progress";

var vals = [id, date, name, surname, serial, eMail, area, text, ans, flag];

var sheetObj = sheet.appendRow(vals);
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('redirect').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

**EDIT**: I tried this code to post a request with JSON

`var d = new Date()
        var val = [idN, d, n, c, m, em, a, t, "", "Ricevuta"];

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/myKey/values/mySheet:append";
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.onreadystatechange == function (){
        if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(json.values);
        }
    };
    var values = JSON.stringify(val);
    xhr.send(values);
    alert('ok');
}`
```

The code is not working, I think the error may be a "401()", and I don't know how to solve... Any help?

Comment: What've you tried? Play around with [Sheets API Javascript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js).

Comment: @noogui I tried this code but it's not working 
`var d = new Date()
  var val = [idN, d, n, c, m, em, a, t, "", "Ricevuta"];
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/myKey/values/mySheet:append";
  xhr.open("POST", url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  xhr.onreadystatechange == function (){
   if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(json.values);
   }
  };
  var values = JSON.stringify(val);
  xhr.send(values);
 }` ideas?

Comment: @noogui here's all my attempts: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44590550/7982055